# how to pass object from view to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

I have an object `$trial` that fills up while in the view. I would like to pass it to route as POST to call a function using it's data. This is to create an event for fullcalendar. I'm pretty sure that I've been sitting on this so long, that I'm way overthinking it.

Wanted to do this with `eventRender` callback but couldn't figure out how to pass the data into it, tried simple `$.post` just to get *method not allowed* or *unknown status* in the console.

I have some dummy data at the moment.

The goal here is to create event through marked time range.

Controller function to add new record to database if I manage to pass data

```
public function addEvent(Request $request)
{
    //dd($request);

    $event = new Event;
    $event->title = $request['title'];
    $event->start_date = $request['start_date'];
    $event->end_date = $request['end_date'];
    $event->save();

    \Session::flash('success','Event added successfully.');
    return redirect('/events');
}
```

web.php (routing)

```
Route::get('/events', 'EventController@index');
Route::post('/events', 'EventController@addEvent');
```

and then there is the index function on which I work the most currently to modify the table (make it editable, etc).

```
public $trial = [];

//
public function index()
{
    $events = [];
    $data = Event::all();
    if($data->count()) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $events[] = Calendar::event(
                $value->title,
                true,
                new \DateTime($value->start_date),
                new \DateTime($value->end_date.' +1 day'),
                null,
                // Add color and link on event
                [
                    'color' => '#f05050',
                    'url' => '/events',


                ]
            );
        }
    }

    $calendar = Calendar::addEvents($events) //add an array with addEvents
    //->addEvent($eloquentEvent, [ //set custom color fo this event
        //'color' => '#800',
    //])
        ->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options
        'firstDay' => 1,
        'selectable' => true,
        'unselectAuto' => false,
        'selectOverlap' => false,
        'editable' => true,
        'businessHours' => [
            'dow' => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
            'start'=> '08:00',
            'end' => '19:00',
        ]

    ])->setCallbacks([ //set fullcalendar callback options (will not be JSON encoded)
        'eventClick' => 'function(event) {
            console.log("You clicked on an event with a title of: " + event.title);
     }',

        'select' => 'function(start, end) {
            console.log("Selection start: " + start.format() + " selection end: " + end.format());

            $trial = {
                title: "rent",
                start_date: start.format(),
                end_date: end.format()
            };
            console.log($trial);


        }',
    ]);
```

any suggestions would be welcome.

EDIT: generally, pretty much the only way i know how to pass data to be used in functions in controller is submitting it through form

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Angular specifically, but it's got many similarities with Vue. I use a platform-agnostic package called Axios which allows you to send requests to your server.

To backtrack a second, a form is basically a general way to send a post request. The url is specified in the form, and the values are the input fields.

With any package, you would do something similar:

- specify the url
- specify the request type (post, get, etc)
- pass parameters (but not required)

With Axios, it would look something like:

```
axios.post('/mySite.com/something', { datum1: 'value', datum2: true })
      .then(response => () {
         this.someFunction(response.data);
      });
```

This has some ES6 magic in it (arrow functions), but this is very similar to many requests. Like I said, the second parameter is optional, or you can even pass a data object.

- Don't forget to also include the csrf token. This is easiest if you just add in as a meta tag in your page head (see the Laravel Docs), but you can also pass it in directly as a `_csrf` parameter.